# Opening a new screen by clicking the button on the existing screen in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on make a twitter website. But I can't solve the this problem. When I want to click this button:

[image: Twitter]

I expect a result like this:

[image: Twitter-form]

Its background will look like this and it will pop a form on the screen. What should I use to solve this problem? I'm not bad with HTML DOM, but I couldn't figure out the algorithm in my head.

Comment: Please add the code to your answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what research you have done and any attempts you have made to solve the issue yourself. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], as well as the instructions presented on the Ask Question pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other way for achieving that, would be with a modal box (div) that already exists but will only be displayed after clicking a certain button.

Here's a quick example, I've also added an overlay, which will appear behind the div. If you click on the overlay while the modal box is visible, it will disappear again.

```js
$('#button').click(() => {
    var display = $('#popup').css('display');
    if (display === "none") {
        $('#popup').show();
        $('#overlay').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('#popup').hide();
        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('#overlay').click(() => {
    $('#popup').hide();
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#popup {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 6%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}

#overlay { 
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div id="button">Click me</div>
        <div id="popup">Text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can use JavaScript or jQuery.

Exemple:

```js
$(".mybutton").click(() => {
   $("body").append(`
    <div class="modals">
      Copy your code here
    </div>
  `)
})
```

```css
.modals{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  padding: 40px 30px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button class="mybutton">Open</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#button').click(() => {
    var display = $('#popup').css('display');
    if (display === "none") {
        $('#popup').show();
        $('#overlay').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('#popup').hide();
        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('#overlay').click(() => {
    $('#popup').hide();
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#popup {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 6%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}

#overlay { 
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div id="button">Click me</div>
        <div id="popup">Text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).